# Implement TabBar Application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I make an app in which First 4 screen has no tab bar But after that each screen has tab Bar.
So i added the tabbar in each nib file.

how can i implement the tabbar so it is working.

Help me!!

Comment: Start with: http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing code it's difficult to see where the error has been made, so i recommend you give the [dev centre](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html) a go :)

Comment: Create a new UITabBarController object.
Create a content view controller for each tab.
Add the view controllers to an array and assign that array to your tab bar controller’s viewControllers property.
Set the tab bar controller as the root view controller of your window (or otherwise present it in your interface).

Comment: but window.rootviewController=tababrController shows tabbar on all scrren . I want tab bar start after 4 screen.

Answer (score 0):

Create tabBarController in your didFinishLaunching, but show it only after you show your first 4 screens without TabBar. This is a default didFinishLaunching, that is generated by Xcode when you chose standart TabBar app template:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Here you should replace this line:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

with your line of showing your controller. Something like this:

```
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
            loginViewController.delegate = self;
self.window.rootViewController = loginViewController;
```

Then, when you remove your last screen and want to show the tab bar, write this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication   sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

The main idea is that you just **change the rootViewController of your app window**.

Comment: Changing rootViewController worked for me, it's not an improvisation. I show login screen, then a  TabBar controller.

Comment: where to write appdelegate.window.rootviewcontroller=self.tabbarcontroller??? In the specific view controller or in appdelegate.m??